# Помогите составить программу в питоне. У самого только бурда получается

Tags: python

Запрашиваются 10 чисел (целые значения от 0 до 1000). Опишите алгоритм, позволяющий найти и вывести минимальное значение среди введенных чисел, которые имеют чётное значение и не делятся на три.[image: моя калека]

Comment: Познайте списки. Код показывайте текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Ребят, плз! В понедельник проверка.

Comment: В сфере разработки питон нельзя копировать пояснения по-моему

Comment: к тому же если разобраться в первых строках, то остальные видеть не потребуется

Comment: может кто-нибудь свой код подскажет?

Comment: @Вован добавьте код вашей программы в текстовой форме, или вопрос будет закрыт

Comment: закрывайте на здоровье, я писал программу сразу в среде разработки и скопировать её не могу.

Comment: @Вован вы за помощью пришли или как? Мы должны с картинки ваш код перепечатвыть?

Comment: Предлагаю алгоритм: вынести в отдельный список все числа удовлетворяющие условию и потом найти минимальное. Реализация в 1-3 строки

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, что объяснения не требуются, потому что желания разобраться все равно нет

```py
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(10)]
valid_numbers = [n for n in numbers if not n % 2 and n % 3]

if valid_numbers:
    print(f"Ответ: {min(valid_numbers)}")
else:
    print('Нет чисел, которые соответствуют условию')
```